# How to prove that $(k+1)^{\frac{1}{k+1}} < k^{\frac{1}{k}} (k >= 3)$ using mathematical induction?

Tags: inequality, induction

I've been trying to solve this for hours, but I just can't seem to do it.
And yes, I know I have to show that $(k+2)^{\frac{1}{k+2}} < ... < (k + 1)^{\frac{1}{k+1}}$ from the starting assumption that $(k+1)^{\frac{1}{k+1}} < k^{\frac{1}{k}}$. Any hints would be highly welcome.

Comment: [typesetting] Use `\geq` [$\geq$] or `\geqslant` [$\geqslant$].

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much, Carlos!